# installing electron app is too slow because of native dependencies that need installing into user end pc

Tags: windows, webpack, windows-installer, electron, electron-packager

I have an electron app with 2 package.json files.

The `root/package.json` has all devDependencies, and the `root/app/package.json` has all dependencies which is necessary for app running.

So I package `app` folder using electron-packager, then build installer for windows using inno setup.

But when I install the app, because the `node_modules` in `app` has too many dependencies, the installer is so slow in order to extract all contents from `node_modules`.

Other apps cost 3-10s for installing, but mine 25-35s.

So what should I do for this? Maybe I can bundle the js using webpack before packaging?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should absolutely use something like `webpack` (or equivalent) to bundle your application. Webpack does an excellent job at tree-shaking your dependencies and only keeping the resultant necessary modules.

I have already posted a possible solution for electron projects, including a build process approach that leads to installation building.  My particular recommendation leaned on utilizing Wix for MSI deployment but the build process items are still applicable (steps 1-6) for anyone wanting to understand a possible process for the items important to doing this work (even if you use another installer). Hope this helps:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46474978/3946706

Answer (score 0):

Are you packaging a web app into electron? The slow packaging time is probably because of bundling web node modules into the electron app which is not necessary.
https://medium.com/@hellobharadwaj/electron-plus-angular-react-why-use-2-different-package-json-files-361ae47d07f3

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."